# Constraint to unconstraint optimization problem by subsitution

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Given the following convex optimization problem

> $\min_{x,p} ||x|| - p$
>
> subject to $p > 0$

Can I change the above to an unconstrained **convex** optimization problem by substituting $c = \log(p)$ and minimize

> $\min_{x,c} ||x|| - \exp(c)$

If this is possible I am interested in literature about this topic, but I couldn't find much.

Edit: This is just a minimal example. The problem in the example is of course unbounded, but I think my full optimization problem adds more complexity than necessary to answer my question.

Comment: Your problem looks unbounded...are you sure it is the correct definition? Take $x=0$ and drive $p$ to infinity...

Comment: I tried to give an minimal example, but failed. There are additional soft-constraints on `x` which can be transformed to a penalizing term in the objective.

Comment: The change you are proposing makes the problem non-convex, actually, as the objective is now the difference of convex functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you reconsider sparing us from the complexity of your problem. I think it's clear that we're all missing something here.

First of all: as I stated in the comment above, your proposed reformulation is *not convex*. Your objective function becomes the difference of two convex functions. Given that you've offered the word "convex" in boldface above I assume that is important to you (and it should be!). So the short, but likely unhelpful, answer to your question is *no*, you cannot do that.

But why would you want to do this in the first place? If you have just a single nonnegativity to deal with, it seems like an unnecessarily complex way to handle it. There's no need to be afraid of constrained convex optimization, *especially* for a simple constraint like that.

Still, suppose you have good reason to limit yourself to unconstrained minimizations. Then we can still dispatch a simple model like this easily. Consider the model
$$\begin{array}{ll}\text{minimize}_{x,p} & f(x,p) \\ \text{subject to} & p > 0 \end{array}$$
where $f$ is convex in $x$ and $p$. Now consider solving a pair of unconstrained problems:
$$\begin{array}{ll}\text{minimize}_{x,p} & f(x,p) \end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}{ll}\text{minimize}_x & f(x,\epsilon) \end{array}$$
for some small $\epsilon>0$ (indeed, $\epsilon=0$ might work depending on some mild continuity conditions on $f$). If the first problem obtains $p>0$, then that is the solution to the constrained problem. If the first problem obtains $p\leq 0$, then the second problem yields the solution to the constrained problem (approximately, if $\epsilon\neq 0$).

In practice, we do not actually have to solve the first problem to completion *if* it is producing $p<0$. We can terminate as soon as we discover (through duality, say) that the optimal solution will have $p\leq 0$. And if you have multiple variables that must be positive, then an active set method might allow us to generalize this approach.

Now, you probably have a very good reason why you can't do something like this. But because you've not shared the full model, we don't know it. *As written*, this is the best we can offer. If you're willing to use constrained optimization machinery, of course, then there are all sorts of options available to you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can do this. If $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism, over the appropriate domains

$$\min_x\ f(x) = \min_y\ (f\circ \phi)(y).$$

I don't know a reference offhand unfortunately, but it is rather intuitive that this should work -- also you can see that $[J\phi]\nabla f = 0$ if and only if $\nabla f =0$ since $J\phi$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are some unstated constraints (otherwise the problem is just unbounded), I would just say

$$min_{x,p} ||x|| - p - \lambda \log(p)$$

where $\lambda$ acts as scaling factor. This is an old-fashioned approach called SUMT that traces back I guess the '60s. It is a seminal method from Fiacco&McCormick. You solve a sequence of convex problem reducing each time lambda, until the solution does not change. These class of methods are part of the interior-point family. They are usually numerically unstable and not very efficient.

As a practical approach, I would instead solve

$$min_{x,p} ||x|| - p$$ 
$$ p\geq \epsilon$$

for decreasing values of $\epsilon$ until either the constraint is not binding, or the solution does not change that much.